# Store and search sets (with many possible values) in a database (from Java)

Tags: java, sql, database, set, nosql

The problem is how to store (and search) a set of items a user likes and dislikes. Although each user may have 2-100 items in their set, the possible values for the items numbers in the tens of thousands (and is expanding).

Associated with each item is a value say from 10 (like) to 0 (neutral) to -10 (dislike).

So given a user with a particular set, how to find users with similar sets (say a percentage overlap on the intersection)? Ideally the set of matches could be reduced via a filter that includes only items with like/dislike values within a certain percentage.

I don't see how to use key/value or column-store for this, and walking relational table of items for each user would seem to consume too many resources. Making the sets into documents would seem to lose clarity.

The web app is in Java. I've searched ORMS, NoSQL, ElasticSearch and related tools and databases. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should investigate recommender systems. I don't think this is the sort of thing that you're going to be able to easily implement with a query or two.

Comment: A specific example may clarify your question and inspire more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems like the actual storage isn’t the problem, but you want to make a suggestion system based on the likes/dislikes.

The point is that you can store things however you want, even in SQL, most SQL RDBMS will be good enough for your data store, but you can of course also use anything else you want. The point, is that no SQL solution (which I know of) will give you good results with this. The thing you are looking for is a suggestion system based on artificial intelligence, and the best one for distributed systems, where they have many libraries implemented, is [Apache Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/).

According to what I’ve learned about it so far, it can do what you need basically out of the box. I know that it’s based on Hadoop and Yarn but I’m not sure if you can import data from anywhere you want, or need to have it in HDFS.

Other option would be to implement a machine learning algorithm on your own, which would run only on one machine, but you just won’t get the results you want with a simple query in any sql system.

The reason you need machine learning algorithms and a query with some numbers won’t be enough in most of the cases, is the diversity of users you are facing… What if you have a user B which liked / disliked everything he has in common with user A the same way - but the coverage is only 15%. On the other hand you have user C which is pretty similar to A (while not at 100%, the directions are pretty much the same) and C has marked over 90% of the things, which A also marked. In this scenario C is much closer to A than B would be, but B has 100% coverage. There are many other scenarios where most simple percentages won’t be enough, and that’s why many companies which have suggestion systems (Amazon, Netflix, Spotify, …) use Apache Mahout and similar systems to get those done.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct, the problem is more complex. I reduced the scope to ask the question. I will invest in learning more about Mahout. Can you recommend the best algorithm(s) for my problem?